# Pines Steps include files

Tags: jquery

I want to use Pines Steps. How to include files for Pines Steps.

when I run this code I'm getting following two errors (Inspect Element).

> 1. Uncaught `ReferenceError: jQuery` is not defined (at line number 12)
> 2. Uncaught `TypeError: $(...).psteps` is not a function (at line number 51)

Please help me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.psteps.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     <style>
        .step-title {
            min-height: 20px;
            float:left;
            border-radius: 0;
        }
        .next-button, .submit-button, .back-button {
            float:right;
            margin:3px;
        }
        @media(max-width:600px) {
            .step-content {
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
        }
        /* Vertical Styles */
        #psteps_simple .step-title {
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-right: 0;
            width: 99.5% !important;
            min-height: 28px;
            display: block;
        }
        #psteps_simple .step-title .step-order {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 12%;
        }
        #psteps_simple .step-title .step-name {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 2%;
        }
        #psteps_simple .step-title[class^="icon-"] {
            float: right;
            margin-right: 7%;
            margin-top: 2%;
        }

    </style>

    <script>
      $('#psteps_simple').psteps();
    </script>


</head>
<body>

    <div id="psteps_simple" class="row-fluid" style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <div class="span2">
    <div class="step-title"><span class="step-order">1.</span>  <span class="step-name">Step 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="step-title"><span class="step-order">2.</span>  <span class="step-name">Step 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="step-title"><span class="step-order">3.</span>  <span class="step-name">Step 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="step-title"><span class="step-order">4.</span>  <span class="step-name">Step 4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="step-title"><span class="step-order">5.</span>  <span class="step-name">Step 5</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span6 well clearfix">
    <div class="step-content">Step 1</div>
    <div class="step-content hide">Step 2</div>
    <div class="step-content hide">Step 3</div>
    <div class="step-content hide">Step 4</div>
    <div class="step-content hide">Step 5</div>
    <button class="next-button btn">Next Step</button>
    <button class="submit-button btn">Done</button>
    <button class="back-button btn">Back Step</button>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script `"jquery.psteps.min.js"` need to be placed after `"jquery.min.js"`, because `"jquery.psteps.min.js"` depends on `"jquery.min.js"`.

1. First error `ReferenceError: jQuery` is came, while loading `jquery.psteps.min.js` file jQuery is passed as a parameter.
2. Second error `TypeError: $(...).psteps` is came, as in the first error, `jQuery` is found to `jquery.psteps.min.js`, so is not loaded into the memory.

Find the following :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.psteps.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

3. Third error: `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(...)`, is came to due you are calling `$('#psteps_simple').psteps();` before the `psteps_simple` div elements loading. For this call `$('#psteps_simple').psteps();` inside of `$(document).ready()` function.

Use the following code:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#psteps_simple').psteps();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: again I got this error..
`Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(...) is not a function`